# How to query array in Postgres json column?

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-json

Thanks in advance. Assume, I have a table that contains the value in an array something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE example (
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    content_type json NULL
    CONSTRAINT example_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

```
id |name |content_type
-----------------------
 1 | P   | ['a','b','c']
 2 | Q   | ['a',]
 3 | R   | ['b','c']
 4 | S   | ['a','c']
```

I want to find which row contains `'c'` in content_type

I have tried but couldn't get,

```
select * from table where ARRAY['c'] && content_type;
```

Is there someone to help me to build the query?

Comment: you can find rows where the array has all values equal to c with: 
SELECT * FROM table WHERE value = ALL (column);

Comment: Unclear. Is `content_type` a char array or a JSON? [Edit] the question and add the `CREATE` statement of the table to clarify. And also why isn't this modeled the relational way? That could have easily been done with another table linking the content types. Then it would be a simple join query...

Comment: @stickybit, thank you for the suggestion. I could have modeled the relational way but for some reasons, I have to follow this.   `content_type` is a JSON column.

Comment: @RakibulIslam Do you really need a JSON column? Can it also hold objects or primitive values instead of arrays? Can the arrays contain anything else than characters? If not, you should change the column type to `char[]` or `text[]`, to make it an actual *array column* (and have Pooya's answer work)

Comment: thank you again. I will try and give feedback here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated for change column type from text[] to json**

If your column type is JSON you can use two scenarios:

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3d8c2ed225c6496fdbe9a51f2d3d4094)

1. convert to **jsonb** and use `?` operator ([Postgres document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html))

```sql
select * from test where content_type::jsonb ? 'c';
```

2. Use `json_array_elements_text`

```sql
select distinct on(t.id) t.*
from 
  test t
  cross join json_array_elements_text(content_type) je
where
  je.value = 'c';
```

---

**Old scenario**

You can use `any` function to check values exist in an array or according to [Postgres document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) use array operator `@>`

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=fd0bfa81aa04241a2768956b0700c620)

1. With `any`

```sql
select * from test where 'c' = any(content_type);
```

2. With `@>`

```sql
select * from test where content_type @> array['c'];
```

Comment: As the data type of `content_type` is JSON, it shows "ERROR: op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side"

Comment: I updated the post for the JSON scenario